# Displaying Time in Reporting Services 2008

Tags: reporting-services, time, reporting

I have a table in my report, where I have columns of datatype `Time(7)`.

Now I have problems formatting them correctly in Reporting Services 2008.

If I set the format of the expression to HH:mm it does still display `11:12:000` !

I want to get only the hours and minutes! like `11:12`

It looks like RS does not know the format. None of the following does work:

```
=Hour(Fields!MyTime.Value)

=CDate(Fields!MyTime.Value)
```

Both throw an error. I think it propably does format it as plain text?

Thanks for your assistance

Edit:

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 Express as the database. (so I include the DataSource in the report, because Reporting Services in SQL Server Express does not allow to use shared DataSources.)

**The Solution (Thanks Mark Bannister):**

```
=Today() + Fields!MyTime.Value
```

Then you can use the common formatting used for datetime values!

Comment: What datasource (SQL/other, SQL dialect, version, etc) are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing `MyTime` with `cast(MyTime as datetime) as MyTime` in your query, and set the format of the expression to `HH:mm`.

Comment: That solves the problem if I do nothing with those time values. But When I do an Addition or Subtratcion 2 of those values I still get the wrong format, because Math with Dates return a timespan I guess... But converting with CDATE(mytime1 +mytime2) doesnt work.

Comment: mytime1+mytime2 shouldn't be a valid expression anyway, as they are both time values - I can't work out what you are trying to achieve with that expression. mytime1-mytime2 would give you a time interval as the difference between the two, except I don't think SQLServer allows datetime arithmetic that way - you would have to use datediff instead. I suggest using the existing date/time functions in SQLServer, such as datepart and datediff.

Comment: you missunderstood me. I do the subtraction off the too dates in the Report! I want to add time1 + time2 and get the total time and display it in the report. That should be possible somehow!

Comment: time1 + time2 does work in the report -> but I lose the correct formatting as HH:mm!

Comment: @SwissCoder, it sounds as though you are treating the time values as though they were time duration - my understanding is that they are actually timestamps (like datetimestamps, but with no date element).

Comment: Thank for your quick replies. What I exactly do is: (time1 -time2)+(time3-time4). So I am adding 2 timespans.. giving my a Timespan as Result I think.. and that Resulting Timespan has the correct value. but I can not display that in the correct format.

Comment: My Problem is not on the SQL-Server side! Its in the formatting of the Report.

Comment: @SwissCoder, the DateTime format property is for datetimestamp values, not duration/timespan values. If you add your duration to a midgnight-valued date, the resultant datetime value can be formatted as HH:mm.

Comment: Hi Mark Bannister, that last comment made it clear to me at second reading! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the expression in with the FORMAT() function.  For example:

You have a textbox, or a datagrid/matrix with the time value in it. Edit the expression as:

```
format( (time1 -time2) + (time3 - time4) , "HH:mm")
```

I often use this with `Datetime` to "cut off" the time when displaying it.

Example

```
format(dateVal,"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

will display

```
10/05/2010
```

Here is a little more info on it which may help out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bz1f0h(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you. But this not work... I think after I subtract one datetime from another datetime I get a timespan or timeoffset.. and somehow that will throw an error when trying to format it as HH:mm